# Windows 11 - Keep Quick Access always visible (freeze on top)

Tags: windows, windows-10-quick-access

Is there a way to keep Quick Access always visible on top so I don't have to scroll to get to it?

edit: To make it more clear, I am only interested  in freezing the Quick Access (shortcuts) because I use it in open/save file dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Access Windows 11 22H2 is just a view in the right hand window. It is no longer part of the file tree on the left. There is not a Quick Access option in File Explorer options any more.

This is an outgrowth of the Tabbed File Explorer.

You need to update to V22H2 and that should fix your issue.

Here is a screen shot of Quick Access as it is now current in Windows 11

[image: Windows 11 22H2 QA]

Comment: To be honest, I am not really sure I understand what you are suggesting. I just wanted to freeze the Quick Access portion so it's always visible, like one can do with rows in Excel.
Regardless, I updated to W11 insider and got the new File Explorer which removed QA entirely and replaced it with Home (that works almost the same as QA). However, Home can't be frozen in place either. Do you know if it's possible to "split" the left pane in two, keep Home always visible on top and scroll only the bottom half?

Comment: The QA portion is now in a window.  You can use another Tab in File Explorer to maintain organization. It is all changing so just make sure Windows 11 is up to date. The screen shot is from an older version just to see if clearing QA helps. It is not needed int the current version.

Comment: I changed the screen shot to show what QA is now. There is no scrolling option. Just Window tabs.

Comment: I got that but I'm still asking if there's a way to freeze that section of the tree. Also, I don't use File Explorer at all, I only care about the tree because it still shows up on open/save file dialogs where I use QA stortcuts.

Comment: For File explorer there is no way to freeze the window in this new explorer. You use different tabs and come back.  So now assuming you are on 22H2 you cannot freeze QA on top

Answer (score 0):

i feel your pain too! Quick access is useless when it comes to saving file, especially in MS Office. The folder tree is long yet when save file MS Office always show default location is My Computer - which is often at the bottom of the list while the location you want to quick save is at QuickAcess at top. Now you have to scroll very long back to the top just to file Quick Acess pinned folder. Such a pain in the ***!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).